# How to check if something in an array is valid in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, null, initialization

I initialize an array of Entity pointers and add entities like this...

```
Entity* ents[16];
Player* player = &Player(20, 24); // subclass of entity
Player* player2 = &Player(30, 30);
ents[0] = player;
ents[1] = player2;
```

I loop through them with 16 as the size since I already know it.

But I can't do anything with them... because some of them are not "valid". I can't run any methods on entities 2-16 because I didn't set what they are. Visual Studio keeps freaking out about an exception. So I try to add an isValid method to the Entity class, I even tried giving it a public boolean and set it to true in the constructor, but ultimately there's no way to check any data about one of these "invalid entities" without getting an exception. So I need to be able to find out if an entity is valid first before I try to do anything at all with it. But how?

Comment: Unless your compiler extends the lifetime of those temporaries, you have dangling pointers to temporaries...

Comment: what it means to be valid is to have been initialized...

Comment: @Omega: None of these elements will ever be initialised, only potentially assigned-to.

Comment: To this day, I'm still surprised that such code compiles. I thought what made rvalues particular was the fact that you couldn't take their address.
Does that not apply to class objects?

Comment: My compiler won't compile that because of taking the address of a temporary.

Comment: @KABoissonneault: It does apply, but VS is "special".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't do *anything* with elements 2-16 because those are invalid pointers. You didn't even set them to NULL. They are just invalid pointers. You cannot call any function through them or anything else.

You could use a pointer value of `nullptr` to indicate "unfilled" array positions but, honestly, you should be using a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Entity>>` to store good pointers to good data and have no "unfilled" array positions at all. The vector will grow as needed.

As it happens, even your so-called "valid" array elements are dangling pointers to temporaries and thus not "valid" in any way at all. I hate that Visual Studio allows this: by the rules of the standard, this program should not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the uninitialized elements in the `ents` array are distinguishable from the initialized values. For example:

```
Entity* ents[16];
Player* player = &Player(20, 24); // subclass of entity
Player* player2 = &Player(30, 30);
ents[0] = player;
ents[1] = player2;
for (size_t i = 2; i < 16; i++)
  ents[i] = 0;

// then elsewhere, you can use
size_t j = 12;
if (ents[j])
{
   // do something with ents[j] because it has a valid pointer 
}
```

But note that this is a simplified answer for your simple question. In general you should use `std::vector` for a container rather than built-in arrays, and smart pointers rather than raw pointers.